# Teamcity: how to send a rest api request to add something to the buildqueue and run it on a specified agent

Tags: rest, teamcity

Basically I know how to do a post request in order to add something to the buildqueue and how to specify parameters, but I don't know which xml I need to supply in order to have the build ran on a specific agent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

following command should help on this:-

http://testuser:testpassword@myteamcity.com/httpAuth/action.html?add2Queue=mybuild&agentId=1

To know the agentid..
Goto the agent and observe the URL in your browser, it should give you all details as :-

https://myteamcity.com/agentDetails.html?**id=1&agentTypeId=1&realAgentName=BuildAgent1**

you can use any agent detail to specify an agent.
Let me know if it helps!

Comment: The solution was indeed when sending the postrequest to the buildqueue to add <agent id=\""+agentid+"\" />, with the agentid being the the internal id of your agent.